# Reflect vs Regex to check for empty JSON array properties in Golang

Tags: json, regex, performance, go

I receive a JSON Array from our Client which properties are empty:

```
[
  {},{},{},{},{}
]
```

Normally it looks like this e.g:

```
[
    {"Name": "foo", "Text": "Costumer"},
    {"Name": "foo", "Text": "Employer"},
    {"Name": "foo", "Text": "Costumer"},
    {"Name": "foo", "Text": "Emplopyer"},
    {"Name": "foo", "Text": "Employer"}
]
```

As far as my teacher said there is 2 possible ways to check for those empty properties:

regexp package && reflect package

***Which should I use for performance?***

And please explain why u would choose that package over the other

Comment: Why use those? It's actually much cleaner (and more robust) to just unmarshal the input into json and check the unmarshaled object. Sure, the json package uses `reflect` internally, so I guess that falls under that category. Oh, and you're asking for opinions, that's pretty much [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). If you're concerned about performance, implement a few solutions and [benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) them.

Comment: thanks for the fast response i will try your way as well

Comment: `regexp` is going to be faster but more error-prone. Probably not a good idea in production code.

Comment: "regexp is going to be faster" -- not something you hear very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most performant and error-proof way would be to manually parse the JSON tokens yourself with [json's Decoder.Token](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token) and related methods. 
 This avoids the `json` package's normal use of Reflect entirely (since you're not unmarshaling into an arbitrary struct), and it avoids error-prone regular expressions. It will likely out-perform regex, too, but a benchmark will be necessary to be sure.

But it will be some verbose, and arguably ugly code.